# Which webkit qt version compiles on kubuntu 11.10

Tags: webkit, kde-plasma, ubuntu

I previously compiled webkit-qt on kubuntu 11.10 from their svn sources. I remember that it worked well with the kubuntu konqueror and rekonq packages, while their webkit packages are useless (very unstable). I had to export QTDIR and to pick an older svn revision because the current one didn't compile. Now I have to reinstall webkit but I do not remember which svn revision I used. Which of their svn revisions compile with --qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current svn revision (114036) of webkit compiles on ubuntu 11.10 with kde 4.8 and all current updates from the backport ppa.

It is sufficient to checkout the Source and Tools subdirectories (the overall repository is very large)

Compilation is with

```
./Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --qt 
sudo make install
```

Segmentation faults may be due to lack of RAM. Possibly the option --no-svg to drop the support can save memory compilation time.

Note that this will install in the default directories replacing present installations. On my system rekonq and konqueror run well with (while the outdated ubuntu webkit packages cause frequent crashes).